# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? tap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined

New to rails, and walking through part 3 of a four part tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeCp6IzOrpk). Have worked through a lot of errors, but this error has me stuck for the past day. Hoping someone can help.

I added the paperclip gem to my app and this error happens when I attempt to create a new book with an image file.

The Error is

**NoMethodError in Books#Create**

> Showing /BookReview/app/views/books/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:
>
> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
>   Did you mean?  tap
>   Trace of template inclusion: app/views/books/new.html.erb

The Application Trace is

> app/views/books/_form.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_books__form_html_erb__680817446_105363440'
>   app/views/books/_form.html.erb:1:in`_app_views_books__form_html_erb__680817446_105363440'
>   app/views/books/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_books_new_html_erb__1556443805_105196100'
>   app/controllers/books_controller.rb:32:in`create'

I think the problem is in my **create action**, within my books controller

```
def create

    @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
    @book.category_id = params[:category_id]        

    if @book.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

When I add the following line directly under **@book.category_id = params[:category_id]** i can submit the form with no errors, but the file is not associated with the book when I look within the console.

**@book.book_img = params[:book_img]**

The last thing is the private action, which I've added the :book_img to.

```
def book_params
 params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author,:category_id, :book_img)
end
```

Hoping someone can help. Thanks ahead of time!

Edit:

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category") %> 
  <%= f.file_field :book_img %> 
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
  <%= f.input :description %> 
  <%= f.input :author %> 
  <%= f.button :submit %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post `_form.html.erb` ?

Comment: `<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category") %>
 <%= f.file_field :book_img %>
 <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
 <%= f.input :description %>
 <%= f.input :author %>
 <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think `@categories` in _form.html.erb is probably nil. In your controller that renders the form make sure you define @categories e.g.

```
@categories = Categories.all
```

Comment: Within the controller I define a new action, which defines categories.

`def new
  @book = current_user.books.build
  @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  
 end`

When I submit the form causing the error I have the create action

`def create

  @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
  @book.category_id = params[:category_id]
  #@book.book_img = params[:book_img]

  if @book.save
   redirect_to root_path
  else
   render 'new'
  end
 end`

Comment: `render 'new'` means render the `new.html.erb` view, so if you have errors then it will render the new template from the create action, and you don't have `@categories` defined in the create action - it is nil.  Not saying this is the specific error you're getting, but Joe is right in that it would cause one if your book has any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I your create action add this also

```
 @categories = Category.all
```

because on error...it is rendering same new.html.erb and  @categories are not there

Comment: If I dont select an image, the form submits fine with the category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 

  <%= f.input :category_id do %>
      <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name,c.id]}, :prompt => "Select a category" %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.file_field :book_img %> 
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
  <%= f.input :description %> 
  <%= f.input :author %> 
  <%= f.button :submit %> 
<% end %>
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
def create      
  if @book = Book.create(book_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
#strong params
def book_params
 params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, :author,:category_id, :book_img).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: Hi @Dkp. I tried to add these, but getting a SyntaxError i cannot identify. 

**SyntaxError in BooksController#new**

/BookReview/app/views/books/_form.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...rompt => "Select a category") );@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^]

[app/views/books/_form.html.erb:2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
app/views/books/new.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_books_new_html_erb___1743874766_94687280'

Comment: Sorry, trying to figure out how to edit my comments to make them more readable. =(

Comment: Okay, found the syntax error, i was missing a ( 

`  <%= f.input(:category_id, Category.all.map{|b| [b.title,b.id]}, :prompt => "Select a category") %> `

Now I am getting **NoMethodError in Books#new**
/BookReview/app/views/books/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `title' for #<Category:0x0000000dc1df60>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/books/new.html.erb

Comment: I have updated the answer. The error which you are getting indicates that `title` is an undefined methid on the object as **Category model** does not have an attribute named `title`. But it has an attribute called `name`, just look at the form now in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @dkp

Still working through it. I added your updated code and it makes sense, however when I change the title to name, I receive an **ArgumentError in Books#new**

BookReview/app/views/books/_form.html.erb where line #2 raised:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2)
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/books/new.html.erb

Comment: I think simple_form_for has a little different syntax for `select` . I have just updated the form , could you give it a try. You can refer:     https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md#wrapping-rails-form-helpers

Comment: Thanks for the resource @dkp

Okay, so it looks like we are getting closer. I am able to render the new book page and can submit it with no errors. However, the record is not being save to the database now. 

After I submit the _form.html.erb I am taken to the index page, which is good. The index page shows a list of books that have been added. The one I submit does not show.

Comment: When I **rails c** to show the last record, it does not show. So I am certain the record is not being saved to the database. 

Also, if I stick in another line of code for the **create** action 'if @book.save
   redirect_to root_path
  else
   render 'new'
  end'

Then it just renders a new form, opposed to **redirect_to root_path**

Comment: If I submit the form for a new book, without attaching an image. The form submits and the book is correctly shown on the index page as it should. The problem is attaching the image through paperclip I think.

Comment: One more thing. On the index page, that displays all the books added. When I click on the book I created after I implemented the code suggestion you provided I receive **NoMethodError in Books#show**

"BookReview/app/views/books/show.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

When I click any of the other books, I view them fine. Only newly created books gives this error.

Comment: @LeoLeGendre with image, when you submit the form, see what error is being raised. Just change `Book.create(book_params)` to `Book.create!(book_params)` - you will get to see the error why the record is not getting created

Comment: I'll check the error in a minute. I just noticed in rails c, that when I look at the last record the category_id is "nill" on all the newly created books.

Comment: Here is the image error-
**ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in BooksController#create**
Validation failed: Book img has contents that are not what they are reported to be

Comment: @LeoLeGendre make sure you are uploading the correct format of image through form. Regarding `category_id`, you can check the `params` whether it has `category_id` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for jumping in with tons of help. I learned a lot. I've solved the issue.

I removed the paperclip gem and installed the most recent version

`gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'`

I reinstalled ImageMagic and added the PATH to my development.rb.

My development.rb originally had: 
`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"`

Since I am on Windows, I had to replace it with `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'` to get it to work.

Now everything is working fine. Thanks again for everyone's help.